# How can I redirect url websitename.com/page1 to websitename.com/awesome/page1. I am using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, url, redirect, cpanel

Example:

- `websitename.com/page1` goes to `websitename.com/awesome/page1`
- `websitename.com/page2` goes to `websitename.com/awesome/page2`
- `websitename.com/page3` goes to `websitename.com/awesome/page3`

I can't seem to find any solution to this.

Answer (score -1):

There are many plugins that will do this, [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) being one of the most popular.

> Redirection is the most popular redirect manager for WordPress. With it you can easily manage 301 redirections, keep track of 404 errors, and generally tidy up any loose ends your site may have. This can help reduce errors and improve your site ranking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I read a bit regarding 301 redirection, does it have an option to have all   websitename.com/page1 have a suffix "/blog" before the main url, then add the "/page1" at the end or (pageX) so it will be  websitename.com/blog/page1 or websitename.com/blog/(pageX)?

Comment: Yes, Redirection supports regular expression redirects. https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer not to use a plugin, you can include this rule in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)/?$ /awesome/page$1 [R=301,L]
```

For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)/?$ /awesome/page$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or you can use this code:

```
add_action('init',function (){
    if(preg_match('#^/page(\d+)$#',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)){
        wp_redirect('/awesome/page' . $matches[1],301);
        exit;
    }
},0);
```

Comment: Note that `.htaccess` is only for Apache servers; according to W3Techs, nginx is the most used web server (as of August 2023).